# Find occurrences of pairs of letters in string with regex

Tags: regex

my code:

```
regex = r"BB"

test_str = "NBCCNBBBCBHCB"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

output:

`Match 1 was found at 5-7: BB`

My question is, why doesnt it match the second pair of BB?

(NBCCNB**BB**CBHCB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason only 1 instance of `BB` is found is your regex *consumes* the input when matching, so the pointer is moved to after the first pair of `BB`, after which there are no more pairs.

Rather than thinking about "pairs", what you want to find is "all B that is followed by B":

```
B(?=B)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/uyqLJmeAbGIzJO) (slightly modified to highlight the quantity of matches).

This find 2 hits as you expect, because only one B is consumed per match (look aheads don't consume input).

Comment: Aahhh thank you! Thats exactly what I was looking for. Not very good at regex and tried to figure it out on https://regex101.com/.